# impala shell command to export a parquet file as a csv

Tags: impala

I have some parquet files stored in HDFS that I want to convert to csv files FIRST and export them in a remote file using ssh.

I don't know if it's possible or simple by writing a spark job (I know that we can convert parquet to csv file JUST by using spark.read.parquet then to the same DF use spark.write as a csv file). But I really wanted to do it by using a impala shell request.

So, I thought about something like this :

```
hdfs dfs -cat my-file.parquet | ssh myserver.com 'cat > /path/to/my-file.csv'
```

Can you help me PLEASE with this request ? Please.
Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

Example without kerberos:

```
impala-shell -i servername:portname -B -q 'select * from table' -o filename '--output_delimiter=\001'
```

I could explain it all, but it is late and here is a link that allows you to do that as well as the header if you want: http://beginnershadoop.com/2019/10/02/impala-export-to-csv/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by multiples ways.

One approach could be as in the example below.

With `impala-shell` you can run a query and pipe to `ssh` to write the output in a remote machine.

```sh
$ impala-shell --quiet --delimited --print_header --output_delimiter=',' -q 'USE fun; SELECT * FROM games' | ssh remoteuser@ip.address.of.remote.machine "cat > /home/..../query.csv"
```

This command change from `default database` to a `fun database` and run a query on it.

You can change the `--output_delimiter='\t'`, `--print_header` or not along with other options.